# Cpp check show Buffer 'tmpf' is being written before its old content has been used

Tags: c, cppcheck

This function is giving me a warning (on the 5th line) on cpp check. I dont know the reason behid this and nor do I know if its this worth fixing.

```
static char *get_file_name(const char *fmt, long n, int has_fmt_spec)
{
    static char tmpf[4096];
    int bytes;
    bytes = has_fmt_spec ? snprintf(tmpf, 4095, fmt, n) : 
        snprintf(tmpf, 4095, "%s%ld", fmt, n);<--- Buffer 'tmpf' is being written before its old content has been used.
    if (bytes >= 4095) {
        printf("file name too long\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return tmpf;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you either use the ternary expression to select the *format* (instead of having two essentially equal function calls), or to use an `if` statement. Alternatively, you can actually *assign* the format to `fmt` if `has_fmt_spec` is zero.

Comment: thank you for the answer... i'll try this out ... But just out of curiosity, is there anything fundamentally wrong with the code ?

Comment: No there's nothing "wrong" with the code, the behavior is well-defined. *Stylistically* it's anther question though... ;)

Comment: I love ternary operators and use them all the time. But their primary benefit is to make code more succinct and readable. If you find the line is getting long and confusing and calling multiple functions and the order of invocation or results is problematic, better (clearer) to just use an if/else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some feedback:

1. **ᴅᴏɴ'ᴛ ʀᴇᴛᴜʀɴ ᴀᴅᴅʀᴇꜱꜱ ᴏꜰ ꜱᴛᴀᴛɪᴄ ʙᴜꜰꜰᴇʀ ꜰʀᴏᴍ ᴀ ꜰᴜɴᴄᴛɪᴏɴ**: Avoid returning a pointer to a static buffer declared in a function. It turns the scoping hierarchy upside down and it's non-reentrant (e.g. not thread-safe). It's error-prone because  the function overwrites the buffer its returning pointers to, that might be held by or used another thread (or even the same thread).  One can easily forget that the memory is volatile, resulting in some pretty insidious problems that can be tough to diagnose, if not immediately, at some point in the ongoing development or expansion of the code.
2. **ʀᴇᴛᴜʀɴ ᴏᴩᴛɪᴍᴀʟ ꜱɪᴢᴇ ʜᴇᴀᴩ ᴩᴏɪɴᴛᴇʀ ꜰʀᴏᴍ ꜰᴜɴᴄᴛɪᴏɴ**: It's more common to allocate memory from the heap and return a pointer, letting the caller free it. The buffer size doesn't need to be fixed at an arbitrary size in this case, as `snprintf()` lets you calculate the length you needed to store result; so you can allocate the correct amount of memory, thus avoiding the need to check for buffer overflow. Ideally, the result buffer size should only limited by the size of the provided arguments, and available memory. The example shows two ways to propagate the heap pointer from the function. One way returns it as the function's return value; the other way passes it via a function argument.
3. **ᴀᴠᴏɪᴅ ᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴀᴛɪɴɢ ᴩʀᴏɢʀᴀᴍ ɪɴ ᴀ ꜰᴜɴᴄᴛɪᴏɴ:** It's generally a bad idea to exit a program from inside a function (particularly a trivial function). It is better to be strategic about error handling, propagating potentially fatal errors up to main() exiting as necessary from there, if the error is non-recoverable and exit is acceptable for the nature of the application (for an embedded system like a toaster oven, or control tower RADAR, it isn't). Customers hate apps exiting unexpectedly and it can have serious repercussions. Don't let it happen for a small unforeseen error in an arbitrary function.
4. **ᴇʀʀᴏʀ ʜᴀɴᴅʟɪɴɢ ɪɴ ꜰᴜɴᴄᴛɪᴏɴ** The error handling in the example below is adequate, but minimal. At the main() level, the example code presumes any error from the function can only be 'out of memory'. Another way to handle it might be be to return one of a number of global error-specific constants (via enumeration, `#define` or `const`), or return an error message via another `char *` argument, or log the error specifics from inside the function and pass up a generic failure code, and let the caller handle the condition (it too passing it upward if un-handlable). Note: `atoi()` used in the example can fail (i.e. if it can't parse given string), but returns 0 if so, so its good enough for this example. The point is - *Always check return values and/or have a well-conceived error handling strategy*. A lot of bugs occur due to unanticipated failures from innocuous seeming functions, and if the return value is not checked/handled it can be very hard to track down.
5. **ᴄᴏɴꜱɪᴅᴇʀ ᴀ ᴍᴏʀᴇ ɢᴇɴᴇʀɪᴄ ꜱᴏʟᴜᴛɪᴏɴ:** Often it is useful to  create generic solutions that can handle arbitrary cases. If I were doing it, I would generally prefer a function that could handle any format specifier and an arbitrary argument list.  But that was overkill for the example.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   /* 
    * This variant of the function returns pointer 
    * via the function return value.  Caller frees.
    */
   static char *getFilename1(const char *fmt, long n)
   {
       size_t size = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, n);
       char *buf = malloc(size);
       if (buf != null)
           snprintf(buf, size, fmt, n);
       return buf;
   }

   /* 
    * This variant of the function returns the pointer 
    * via a function argument.  Caller frees.
    */
   static int getFilename2(char **bufp, const char *fmt, long n)
   {
       size_t size = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, n);
       if ((*buf = malloc(size)) != null) {
           snprintf(buf, size, fmt, n);
           return 0;
       }
       return -1;
   }

   int
   main(int argc, char **argv) 
   {
       char *filename;
       int n = 0;

       if (argc > 1) 
           n = atoi(argv[1]);

       /* Obtaining buffer pointer as return value */

       if ((filename = getFilename1("file#%d", n)) == null) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("Filename = %s\n", filename);
       free(filename);

       /* Obtaining pointer via function argument */

       if ((getFilename2(&filename, "file#%d", n) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }
       printf("Filename = %s\n", filename);
       free(filename);

       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```